# Rest Request not mapped to object

Tags: java, rest

I have the following request JSON body:

[image: Request body]

and at backend I have this REST method:

```
@JsonView(RestServiceResponseView.InstitutionUserConnectionAndSchedulerPublic.class)
@RequestMapping(value = "/schedules/{institutionuserconnectionid}", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody List<ScheduleResponseWrapper> createScheduleIntervalContainers(
        @PathVariable(value = "institutionuserconnectionid")
        final String institutionUserConnectionId,
        final @RequestBody(required = true) ScheduleIntervalContainerWrapper scheduleIntervalContainerWrapper) throws BusinessException {
```

ScheduleIntervalContainerWrapper looks like this:

```
public class ScheduleIntervalContainerWrapper implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 5430337066683314866L;
private String start;
private String end;
private String startTime;
private String endTime;

public ScheduleIntervalContainerWrapper() {
}

public String getStart() {
    return start;
}

public void setStart(final String start) {
    this.start = start;
}

public String getEnd() {
    return end;
}
```

the ScheduleIntervalContainerWrapper- object at rest method is not null but the fields are not null. If I use a String instead of ScheduleIntervalContainerWrapper- object at rest service method than JSON- String is ok - therefore JacksonMapper can not map the fields but I don't know why.
Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jackson cannot map your JSON into the object because your JSON contains a single element that is not found within the fields of `ScheduleIntervalContainerWrapper` namely `scheduleIntervalContainerWrapper`.

You can either use Jackson to unwrap your JSON, using

```
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
```

and annotating your model with `@JsonRootName(value = "scheduleIntervalContainerWrapper");`

Or you could simply send the JSON without the wrapper :

```
{"start" : "13.10.2015", "end" : "13.10.2015", "startTime": "7.0", "endTime" : "19.0"}
```